# how to optimize project using requireJS if we have defined some maps in config?

Tags: javascript, optimization, module, requirejs

I have a require.config in my main like the following.

> require.config({
>          baseUrl:'scripts/',
>
> ```
>  paths:{  
>         jquery:'shell/lib/jquery/jquery-1.7.1'
>      // many libraries and modules are aliased here
>
>  },
>  map:{
>   '*':{
>       'underscore':'shell/lib/underscore/underscore'
>             // a few other modules are mapped here
>   }
>  }
> ```
>
> });

I did this because the files defined in map are using internal dependencies(in their respective folders) using relative paths.
Now when I run optimizer, the modules defined in path are saved as module IDs, like jquery saved as **jquery** while those in map are getting complete paths, like 'underscore' as 'shell/lib/underscore/underscore' instead of 'underscore'.

This is causing problems as I am using 'underscore' in other modules also and there the optimized file is having 'underscore' instead of 'shell/lib/underscore/underscore'.

Is there some specific way to optimize when we give map configs or something I am missing? Please tell me how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: It's not very clear why you're trying to put Underscore into maps. Maps are useful when different modules in your app depend on different versions of Underscore. If all of your apps depend on one version of Underscore, put it input paths. Please clarify in the comments, and I will try to help you with this.

Comment: This underscore is a wrapper .js file written over the underscore library which says require[("./underscore-1.3.3").... This is done because one team tests and defines which open source libraries to use and other teams use them. Such implementation is also made use of when writing custom extensions of open source libraries like Animation.js. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the issue:

> This is causing problems as I am using 'underscore' in other modules also and there the optimized file is having 'underscore' instead of 'shell/lib/underscore/underscore'.

This seems to be the expected behavior, you mapped `underscore` to that path for all modules. So basically you are telling to `r.js`: each time that you find the `underscore` dependency rewrite it to `shell/lib/underscore/underscore`. If your modules use "internal paths" and you want do do the opposite (make them to reference `underscore`), you need to do the opposite mapping:

```
 'some/path/underscore': 'underscore'
```

In that case all the modules will be pointing to the same underscore module. Even those that use some strange path for underscore.

In the extreme case that you need to control how `r.js` writes modules on disk. You can use the `onBuildWrite` property (see https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L517).

For example:

```
onBuildWrite: function ( moduleName, path, contents ) {
    if ( path === './src/somefile.js' ) {
          return contents.replace(/^define\('src\/underscore'/, "define('underscore'");
    } else {
          return contents;
    }
}
```

This example is a "hack" that tell to `r.js`: when you process `somefile.js`, replace `src/underscore` with `underscore` (is exactly what you do with map... but is just to show you how you can use `onBuildWrite` to do nasty things).